# Excel calculating every two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this code that calculates hours worked each day, and i want to sum them up for the whole row. Every pair of columns are time started and time ended. So C4 is startind hour at day 1 and D4 is ending hour at day 1, etc.
is there a formula to automate this and not write every column formula seperately? The sum works but its too big as a formula'''MOD(D4-C4;1)24-(D4<C4)(22-6)-MEDIAN(D424;6;22)+MEDIAN(C424;6;22)+
MOD(F4-E4;1)24-(F4<E4)(22-6)-MEDIAN(F424;6;22)+MEDIAN(E424;6;22)+
MOD(H4-G4;1)24-(H4<G4)(22-6)-MEDIAN(H424;6;22)+MEDIAN(G424;6;22)+''' etc etc

[image]

Comment: Should upload data example and expected output

Comment: Will matter a lot what version of Excel you have.  But it's really hard to understand the logic you're using, so as user11222393 said, I don't think we can help without some sample data.

Comment: I have uploaded the demo file here https://easyupload.io/3m07v1

Comment: i added the file as a link and a picture if that helps